# git merge only merging last commit

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch I worked on some time ago that I need to merge into my main branch, it has several commits yet when I try and merge it it only merges in the last commit on the branch and not others that haven't been merged in. Is there a way I can selectively merge commits? Or some way to solve this issue?

Comment: Just read any tutorial, it usually explains how merge works. E.g. here it has a picture to illustrate: https://people.gnome.org/~federico/news-2008-12.html

Comment: What your describing doesn't sound possible unless the earlier commits had already been merged.  You can use `git merge-base --is-ancestor` to confirm.

Comment: I found the issue checking git reflog. The thing is I did in fact merge the branch, but I reverted it, but now I guess my main branch is taking it as if those changes are already merged so it won't merge them again.

Comment: You are correct.  Since you merged in the branch already, git sees those changes as already existing on the branch so it won't bring them when you do a merge again.  To get those changes back, revert your revert commit or cherry pick the commits from the branch which will create new commits with the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cherry-pick that commit:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

Comment: Mind being a little bit more verbose on how to do this properly? I got could not apply.

Comment: Did a little more research on it and got it working, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cherry-pick to solve that issue :

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

but did you make a pull request?

you can check with this link
https://learngitbranching.js.org/