# How to preserve changes to same file on main and feature branch during git merge?

Tags: git, merge

I have a main branch and a feature branch. In the time since the feature branch was created, changes have been made to a file, 'example.txt,' on the main branch. The feature branch also makes changes to example.txt.

I'm currently trying to catch the feature branch up to main. When I merge main in, I lose most of the changes I made to example.txt on the feature branch. In the past git has warned me of merge conflicts and let me resolve them. This time, it's ignoring all of the commits except the most recent from the feature branch. Why is this happening? How can I keep the changes made on main and on the feature branch?

Git commands:

```
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout feature/the-feature-branch
git merge main
git pull
```

I expect this to either merge the changes made on main and feature (preserving all changes) or warn me of a conflict and let me resolve it. Instead, it is only keeping changes from main branch and the most recent commit from the feature branch.

EDIT: edited to add that the most recent commit from the feature branch is included.

Comment: why are you mixing up `main` and `master`?

Comment: @eftshift0 Fixed. My organization just switched from master to main. Fingers are still getting used to the change. Thanks.

Comment: Have you pushed the feature branch as a PR yet? If not, just fetch and rebase.

Comment: What you described is not the normal way `git merge` works.... you sure there is no more magic involved? Let's go to basics... run `git merge-base main feature/the-feature-branch`. That will give you a commit. Then, do `git  diff <that-commit> main -- the-file` and `git diff <that-commit> feature/the-feature-branch -- the-file` and you should see the 2 sets of changes that you would like to keep when you merge the 2 branches. is that the case?

Comment: @matt, the feature branch has been pushed already. I inherited this change from someone else.

Comment: @eftshift0, this is not the case `git diff ... main` shows all of the changes from main. `git diff ... feature/the-feature-branch` only shows the most recent commit from the feature branch. That commit only contained a typo fix, so I didn't realize it was being included in the merge. Looks like it is leaving out previous commits, though.

Answer (score -1):

This was happening because part of the feature branch had been previously merged into main (and later reverted). The comments/answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553153/git-merge-only-merging-last-commit) explain the problem and solution.